# How to use <img src= > with Ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, src

I am trying to insert pictures to id "pokedex-view" by using Ajax GET. I think "spriteurl" is showing the correct path. But  does not work correctly, and it cannot find the pciture for the local folder. Is there something wrong in this code. Thanks.

```
    function populatePokedex() {

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", "https://webster.cs.washington.edu/pokedex/pokedex.php?pokedex=all");
    xhr.onload = function(){
        if (this.status == 200) {
            var picArr = this.responseText.split("\n");

            for(var i=0; i < picArr.length; i++){
                var eachName = picArr[i].split(":")
                var spriteurl = "/Pokedex/sprites/" + eachName[1];
                document.getElementById("pokedex-view").innerHTML += spriteurl
                document.getElementById("pokedex-view").innerHTML += "<img src = spriteurl>";
            }
        } else {
            document.getElementById("pokedex-view").innerHTML = "ERROR: Status: " + this.status + ", " + this.statusText;
        }
    }
    xhr.onerror = function(){
        document.getElementById("pokedex-view").innerHTML = "ERROR";
    }
    xhr.send();
    }
```

Comment: What does your html look like, specifically the parts pertaining to the `pokedex-view`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to concatenate or to interpolate the way you assign the `spriteurl` as the `src` attribute:

```
document.getElementById("pokedex-view").innerHTML += '<img src="' + spriteurl + '">'
```

Or:

```
document.getElementById("pokedex-view").innerHTML += `<img src="${spriteurl}">`
```

Comment: Yeah I did! That was helpful.